# Nodejs error send error response for Jquery to catch

Tags: jquery, node.js

I have a route in Nodejs where I am throwing an error from:

```
router.post("/someRoute",(req,res)=>{
   try{
       if(!someCondition){
           const err = new Error('Part Not Found')
           err.statusCode = 404;
           throw err;
       }
   }
   catch(err){
         res.send(err)
  }

}
```

In my jquery ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/someRoute",
        data: {
            data: $(".data").val(),
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Success")
        },
        error:function(err){
            $.toast({
                title: err.message,
                subtitle: 'Just Now',
                content: err.message,
                type: 'danger',
                delay: 5000
            });
        }
    })
```

However, the success function is jquery is firing instead of the failure function.

Comment: `catch` will trigger if there is an actual error. You are trying to error on a `try` block which goes okay and means  `status` 200. Ajax `j Query` will only trigger error once catch block will throw error.

Comment: I am sure that the catch block fires because I am using a debugger to step over my code and I can see that the error makes it jump to the catch block

Comment: Whats your ajax `url` network status is it 200 on that route ?